# XSLT Removing node having same name as with another namespaced/prefixed node using local-name()

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to remove `<create>` and `<accountNumber>` from my XML.

I managed to remove `<create>` and keep its child nodes using `//*[local-name()='create']` which is all good.

**Problem :**

`<accountNumber>` has the same name with `<ns2:accountNumber>`

When I do `//*[local-name()='accountNumber']` , it removes both `<accountNumber>` and `<ns2:accountNumber>`. I want to keep `<ns2:accountNumber>`

**Sample Input XML**

```
<root xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1" 
        xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example/v2">
        
    <accountNumber>1234567</accountNumber>
    <create>
        <ns2:profile>
            <ns2:accountNumber>1234567</ns2:accountNumber>
        </ns2:profile>
    </create>
</root>
```

**Desired Output  XML**

```
<root xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1" 
        xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example.com/v2">

        <ns2:profile>
            <ns2:accountNumber>1234567</ns2:accountNumber>
        </ns2:profile>
</root>
```

**My XSL code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"
    xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example.com/v2">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- Copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="//*[local-name()='create'] | //*[local-name()='accountNumber']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I still can't figure out how to refer correctly to `<accountNumber>` without affecting the namespaced/prefixed `<ns2:accountNumber>`

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks like you've formed a bit of a bad habit with this `[local-name()='x']` coding style, which is basically there for people who don't want to think about namespaces -- but in this case you have to think about namespaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ignoring the namespace, use it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.example.com/v1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="create">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="accountNumber"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k. I was not aware of `xpath-default-namespace` in xsl. Your answer solved my problem. Appreciate it.